# Есть ли способ создать виджет поверх всех окон?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Только недавно начал изучать dart+flutter. Ищу способ создать виджет, который накладывается поверх всех окон, чтобы он располагался где нибудь в уголке и при нажатии на него вызывалась какая-нибудь функция. Что-то вроде этого(синий кружочек с иконкой, постоянно на экране): [image: пример]
Не обязательно прилагать код, можно просто ссылку на документацию с подобным виджетом.

Comment: к сожалению flutter не предоставляет таких возможностей. Вам придется это реализовать нативными способами, притом только на android (у ios вообще нет виджетов, пока...).

Comment: @MiT, можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, что значит "нативными способами" и получится ли использовать их вместе со flutter? Я новичок в разработке под андроид, так что лучше поподробнее.

Comment: "нативными способами" означает, с использованием языка Kotlin/Java на Android или Swift/Obj-C на iOS как отдельное приложение. Вам уже ответили как это можно сделать на Android. Но как по мне это лишний хлам, я бы сразу удалил такое приложение...

Comment: @MiT приложением буду пользоваться только я (ну и может ещё один-два человека). Т.е на flutter такую штуку не выйдет сделать?

Comment: нет, не получиться.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно создать свой window manager с параметром `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`, добавив в него нужное view, java пример:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);
    myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           return true;
       }
     });

    wm.addView(myView, params);
```

Для этого требуется разрешение, которое начиная с 23 api надо получать динамически

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`

Либо можно использовать [Bubble Api](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/bubbles) но этот функционал доступен только после включения настройки в developer options, то есть он не для production кода, а так же стоит учитывать то что в Android 11 его планируют сделать доступным для всех и возможно что-то поменять в самом апи.